# updating mysql connector from v3 to v5 caused Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

Tags: mysql

updating mysql connector from v3 to v5 caused  Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed exception,  why is that?

How should I change my code?

Comment: is this related to strict mode in mysql server ver5 or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the source included in the Exception and find out why you use a closed ResultSet.
Check where the ResultSet is created and where it is closed. the method `ResultSet.isClosed()` might be helpful for additional log-messages.

Comment: Thanks but the code works ok with MYSQL server v4 but fails with v5.   The code seem to be OK; RS is not closed